# Cakephp3 redirects back to login page immediately after successfully logging in user

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a small application in cake php3 which has a front end and and an admin backend. I am trying to secure the controllers in the admin backend to require authentication before a user proceeds but after following the tutorial on cakephp3 http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html, I discover the $this->Auth->user() returns null and the users is redirected back to the login page immediately.

my login function in /src/Controller/Admin/UsersController.php

```
public function login() {
     if ($this->request->is ( 'post' )) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify ();
        if ($user) {
                die(var_dump($user));// returns the user details correctly
                $this->Auth->setUser ( $user );             
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl()); 
        }            
        $this->Flash->error ( __ ( 'Invalid username or password, try again' ) );

     }          
}



public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter ( $event );
    $this->Auth->allow ( [  'logout'    ] );
}
```

And in my route i have

```
 Router::prefix ( 'admin', function ($routes) {
$routes->connect ( '/', [ 
        'controller' => 'Admin',
        'action' => 'dashboard' 
]);
$routes->connect ( '/pages/*', [
        'controller' => 'Admin',
        'action' => 'dashboard'
] );

$routes->fallbacks ( 'InflectedRoute' );
```

} );

In my APPController, I have this

```
public function initialize() {
    $this->loadComponent ( 'Flash' );
    // $this->loadComponent('Auth');
    $this->loadComponent ( 'Auth', [ 
            'authorize' => ['Controller'], // Added this line
            'loginRedirect' => [ 
                    'controller' => 'Admin',
                    'action' => 'dashboard' 
            ],
            'logoutRedirect' => [ 
                    'controller' => 'Users',
                    'action' => 'login' 
            ],
            'authenticate'=> [
            'Form' => [
                    'fields' => [
                            'username' => 'email',
                            'password' => 'password'
                    ]
                    ]
                ]
    ] );


}
public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {

    if ((isset ( $this->request->prefix ) && ($this->request->prefix === 'admin'))) {
        $this->layout = 'admin';
    }


    //exit(var_dump($this->Auth->user()));

    if ($this->request->prefix !== 'admin') {
        $this->Auth->allow (); //allow all other parts of the site to work
    }



}

public function isAuthorized($user) {

    if (isset ( $user ['role'] ) && $user ['role'] === 'admin') {
        return true;
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}
```

In my /src/COntroller/Admin/AdminController.php, i have this;

```
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter ( $event );

}

public function index() {

    return $this -> render('TestView/index');

}

public function dashboard(){

}
```

Any help i get wold be appreciated. I have been cracking and searching the internet for couple of days now. I am new to cakephp but i believe i must have done something wrong. I can provide more insights to the code if required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you store passwords in your DB? They need to be hashed in a specific way for Cake to be able to authenticate users. See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords.

Comment: I stored the password using the normal hash method in the cake php documentation. The credentials are working ok. when i try an invalid credential, I get the "Invalid username/password" message. But when i try the valid one, it redirects back to the login page with no message

Comment: What happens if you change your `isAuthorized` method so it always return `true`?

Comment: The method is never called!

Comment: You appear to be only allowing logout via `$this->Auth->allow` try adding `login` to that

Comment: Tried that too @MattStephens, but it dint work

Comment: Did you ever get to solve it?I am facing this issue as on today.

Comment: @Karma, I was not able to resolve it. I had to move back to version 2

Comment: @FagbolaSodiqDamilola check this out https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7621

Comment: I think it might have something to do with you using `$this->Auth->allow()` in the AppController. See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public where is says you should not add the login action and by not having any arguments when you call `$this->Auth->allow()` you are allowing the login action.